# ¿Cómo imprimir las líneas de un archivo usando python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.x

La solución que encontré esta en la documentación de Python 2.7:

```
#!/usr/bin
#
# Open a file
#
file = open('prueba.txt')

linesFile = file.readlines()

for line in linesFile:
    print line

file.close()
```

Y la salida que da es:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1504\cocoasubrtf600

{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}

{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}

{\*\expandedcolortbl;\csgray\c100000;}

\paperw11900\paperh16840\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0

\pard\tx566\tx1133\tx1700\tx2267\tx2834\tx3401\tx3968\tx4535\tx5102\tx5669\tx6236\tx6803\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0



\f0\fs24 \cf0 hola soy una prueba}
```

Entonces no sé qué método debo usar, para que solo imprima 'hola soy una prueba'

Answer (score 2):

Aunque tenga extensión .txt, el fichero contiene texto "enriquecido" (con formato) Puedes probar a usar alguna librería python que maneje el formato (una vuelta rápida por Google me ha dado esto: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyth/) o, si tienes claro qué línea buscas, localizarla con un find() de los caracteres que la preceden.

Comenta cuál es tu intención (supongo que estás haciendo pruebas)

Comment: La intención es: para cada i-esima fila pasarla a una variable, luego borrar dicha linea y pasar a la siguiente. Lo he hecho con el método find(), pero la cuestión es y si no conozco la linea que busco, sino que quiero iterar con todas sus n filas.

Comment: @BigHelmet, en lugar de este comentario, edita la pregunta para añadir **exactamente** qué es lo que quieres. ¿Qué es eso de *"borrar dicha línea y pasar a la siguiente"*?¿Pretendes editar el fichero? [[**..y no me respondas a este comentario, edita la pregunta original**]]